# Iterator of list of list of iterables

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iterable

I would like to iterate of a list of list of Iterables in Python3.

Stated differently, I have a matrix of iterables and I would like to loop through and get at each iteration a matrix of values.  More concretely, I have several files (the rows) which have multiple versions of them (the columns) and I would like at each iteration, get a tuple/matrix containing the first line of all my files and so on.

So, given something like this

```
a = [
  [iter(range(1,10)), iter(range(11,20)), iter(range(21,30))],
  [iter(range(101,110)), iter(range(111,120)), iter(range(121,130))]
]
```

I would like to to

```
for sources_with_their_factors in MAGIC_HERE(a):
  print(sources_with_their_factors)
```

and get

```
((1,11,21), (101,111,121))
((2,12,22), (102,112,122))
…
```

I tried

```
for b in zip(zip(*zip(*a))):
    ...:     print(b)
    ...:
((<range_iterator object at 0x2b688d65b630>, <range_iterator object at 0x2b688d65b7e0>, <range_iterator object at 0x2b688d65b540>),)
((<range_iterator object at 0x2b688d65ba50>, <range_iterator object at 0x2b688d65b6f0>, <range_iterator object at 0x2b688d65b0c0>),)
```

But it isn’t iterating my ranges.

Comment: [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to chain my iteratable.  Chaining would serialize my files and I want to iterate over them in parallel.

Comment: `zip` seems the way. Pass all lists as arguments to `zip` function.

Comment: you should not write the answer in your question. Accept and eventually upvote the answer directly

Comment: If you don't know how to accept an answer, check [how to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you can `zip` the iterators in each sublist together, you're just missing how to `zip` the resulting iterators together.  I would unpack a generator expression:

```
for t in zip(*(zip(*l) for l in a)):
    print(t)

((1, 11, 21), (101, 111, 121))
((2, 12, 22), (102, 112, 122))
...
```

Comment: NICE! this is exactly what I needed. +1

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use indexes?

```
for i in range(len(a[0][0])):
    tupA = (a[0][0][i], a[0][1][i], a[0][2][i])
    tupB = (a[1][0][i], a[1][1][i], a[1][2][i])
    print((tupA, tupB))
```

EDIT: this is a simple way - the way I ( a simpleton ) would do it. *zip* will be much more elegant and effective.